# How can I determine the precise set of environment variables a systemd EnvironmentFile would set?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, systemd

systemd has [an `EnvironmentFile` directive](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=), which sets environment variables from a file's contents based on a number of rules, which are not *quite* equivalent to how a shell would parse that file.

How can I parse a systemd `EnvironmentFile` in *exactly* the same way that systemd itself would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surest thing is to let systemd parse the file itself, via a transient service. Thus:

```
# emit a NUL-delimited set of key=value definitions for environment variables defined by a set of files
newVarsForFile_nullsep() {
  local -a extraParams=( ); local file
  (( $# )) || return 0 # no files specified, nothing to do
  for file in "$@"; do
    extraParams+=( --property=EnvironmentFile="$file" )
  done
  comm -z -23 \
    <(sort -z < <(systemd-run --user --pipe "${extraParams[@]}" grep -zvE '^INVOCATION_ID=' /proc/self/environ </dev/null)) \
    <(sort -z < <(systemd-run --user --pipe grep -zvE '^INVOCATION_ID=' /proc/self/environ </dev/null) )
}

# emit code that can be eval'd in an instance of bash to precisely define the exact variables
newVarsForFile_shellscript() {
  while IFS= read -r -d '' vardef; do
    printf '%s=%q\n' "${vardef%%=*}" "${vardef#*=}"
  done < <(newVarsForFile_nullsep "$@")
}
```

Thereafter, one may invoke (as an example):

```
newVarsForFile_shellscript /etc/conf.d/*.conf
```

...to emit a shell script fragment which, when executed by bash, will set all the same environment variables that adding the relevant `EnvironmentFile`s to a service definition would set.

Comment: I was given a pointer in the right direction by damjan in the systemd IRC channel; credit where due. :)

Comment: Due to the use of the `--pipe` parameter, this unfortunately does not work on systemd versions before 235

Comment: wouldn't the "can be eval'd" in bash that is pretty much left as an exercise to the reader here leave room for differences to slip back in? i.e. isn't there danger that that process interprets certain characters as special in some way, which systemd wouldn't?

Comment: @KlaasvanSchelven since it's bash doing the generation, and bash doing the consumption, as long as it's the same version of bash on both sides of the process there's no room for divergence without a major bug in the interpreter. And I do mean "major" -- the interesting syntax extensions are all in space undefined by the POSIX standard. How parsing quoted strings works is generally quite well-defined; the sole extension to that is ANSI C-like strings, which are adopted from a different standard, but still one that doesn't allow much room for extensions.

Comment: (except adding new backslash-escape characters maybe, but that's only relevant if the generation code _uses_ those characters; if code generation is done by an interpreter release that doesn't know about a given escape sequence, the string would just _not use_ that escape sequence -- putting a literal tab in place if `\t` if we had a hypothetical interpreter that didn't know that `\t` existed inside `$''`, for example)

Comment: @KlaasvanSchelven, ... There would be risk involved if `printf %q` tried to use quotes only when absolutely unavoidable -- leaving anything not recognized as unambiguously valid syntax unquoted -- but that's not the case. The newer (bash 5.0) `${var@Q}` is even more conservative, using a single-quoted context (which POSIX defines rigorously) by default.

Comment: @KlaasvanSchelven, ... But then, maybe I misunderstood your point. "Can be evaled" is **not** an exercise given to the reader to fulfill; rather, it's a guarantee the comment documents as being made by the output of the function at hand (a guarantee provided by virtue of `printf %q` semantics).

Comment: Reading this code, malicious variable names could be an issue (it probably behooves the function to filter for names that POSIX specifies as permissible -- I'm going to go back and do that), but any possible value will be represented safely.